# How to write write if statement inside loop in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
  <div className="pagination">
  <br />
    <center>
        {[...Array(this.props.pages+1)].map((x, i) =>
          <h2 key={i} onClick={()=>this.demoMethod(i+1)} className="tc">{ i+1 }</h2>
        )}
    </center>
  </div>
```

Here in my code i wants to write if else statement .
Actually it is a pagination logic.
i wants to change color of h2 for active page. so i wants to write if statement inside this.

Please share any idea how i can do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write if else as follows:

```
// active is a boolean variable having value true or false
<div className="pagination" style={{color: active? 'red' : 'blue'}}>
```

Inside loop it can as follows:

```
{[...Array(this.props.pages+1)].map((x, i) => {
   if(x) {
      return <h2 key={i} onClick={()=>this.demoMethod(i+1)} className="tc">{ i+1 }</h2>
     } else {
       return <p>my paragraph</p>
      }
   }
)}
```